# Optimize time access to sqlite using coredata

Tags: iphone, sqlite, optimization, core-data, time

I'm trying to use a pre-generated sqlite file containing 10 000 objects in a table.

I've created and added objects, with iPhone simulator, in the sqlite using coredata.

I've copy and past the sqlite contained in iPhone Simulator ressource folder (containing 10 000 objects), into my ressource folder in my project directory.

What i do at first launch of my app, is copy this generated database into my app document directory on the iphone using :

```
NSBundle * mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *oldPath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"MyBase" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSString *newPath = [[app_delegate applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyBase.sqlite"];
        BOOL copied = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error];
        if (!copied) {
            NSLog(@"Moving database from %@ to %@, error: %@", oldPath, newPath, error);
        }
```

It works fine, but i have the following problem :
Comparing access to the original MyBase.sqlite (created on my device and filled with the same 10 000 objects) with the new copy, all access on tables take 3 times more time than on the normal generated MyBase.sqlite.

I wonder if when generating sqlite on simulator, indexed attribute does not exist? 
I need help!

Comment: did you check the indexed checkbox for the object attribute you're accessing?

Answer (score 0):

Your using a fairly common technique and it does not normally cause any issues. Core Data cannot tell the difference between a store just created and an old one if both stores use the same data model.

The only explanation I can think of is that you are using two different system/API versions such that the store file is subtly different. If the version on device is older/newer than the version on simulator you might have problems.

That's just a wild guess.